# How to share some patches?

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I tried to use some packages with new Fuerte Beta 1, but in some reasons they did not work. I fixed this problems and made patches. What is appropriate way to share them? Some packages seems to be abandoned.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31468/how-to-share-some-patches?/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you already have patches, the best thing to do is to find the correct bug tracker for your package and create a bug report and attach your patch to the bug report.

If it is urgent, you can then email ros-users@code.ros.org with the bug id which helps make sure nothing gets lost.

Many package's bug trackers are on http://kforge.ros.org/projects/

For example if you have a TurtleBot related problem, bug reports can be submitted to http://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac

Also many packages and stack list the tracker in their documentation such as http://ros.org/wiki/ros_comm which has a bug tracker at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=ros_comm&type=defect&&ros_comm

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4